# How can I visualize flowmap with R code in Power BI?

Tags: r, powerbi

I want to create a flowmap using flowmapblue in Power BI using R code. You can se my code below. The map is not appearing..I don't know what I did wrong. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong? The code works fine in Rstudio and the map appears.

The first 4 lines commented (#) are from power bi.

```
# The following code to create a dataframe and remove duplicated rows is always executed and acts as a preamble for your script: 

# dataset <- data.frame(count, origin, dest, id, lat, lon)
# dataset <- unique(dataset)

# Paste or type your script code here:

library(htmlwidgets)
library(flowmapblue)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)


flows <- dataset %>% select(count, origin, dest)

flows <- flows %>% group_by(origin, dest) %>% summarize(count = sum(count))
flows <- flows[!(flows$dest == "-1"),]
flows$count <- gsub(",", "\\.", flows$count)


locations <- dataset %>% select(id, lat, lon)

locations$lat <- gsub(",", "\\.", locations$lat)
locations$lon <- gsub(",", "\\.", locations$lon)
locations$lat <- as.numeric(locations$lat)
locations$lon <- as.numeric(locations$lon)
locations$id <- as.character(locations$id)

flowmapblue <- function(
    locations, flows,
    mapboxAccessToken = NULL,
    clustering = TRUE,
    animation = FALSE,
    darkMode = TRUE
) {
  # pass the data and settings using 'x'
  x <- list(
    locations = locations,
    flows = flows,
    mapboxAccessToken = mapboxAccessToken,
    clustering = clustering,
    animation = animation,
    darkMode = darkMode
  )
  # create widget
  htmlwidgets::createWidget(
    name = 'flowmapblue',
    x,
    width = NULL,
    height = NULL,
    package = 'flowmapblue',
    sizingPolicy = sizingPolicy(
      padding = 0,
      browser.padding = 0
    )
  )
}

mapboxAccessToken <- 'mytoken'

flowmapblue(locations, flows, mapboxAccessToken, darkMode=TRUE, clustering = TRUE, animation = FALSE)
```